# Fast way to collect spark dataframe column value into a list (scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, distinct

I am trying to collect the distinct values of a spark dataframe column into a list using scala. I have tried different options:

- `df.select(columns_name).distinct().rdd.map(r => r(0).toString).collect().toList`
- `df.groupBy(col(column_name)).agg(collect_list(col(column_name))).rdd.map(r => r(0).toString).collect().toList`

and they both work, but for the volume of my data, the process is pretty slow, so I am trying to speed things up. Does anyone have a suggestion I could try?

I am using Spark 2.1.1

thanks!

Comment: Using a `collect()` should already be a collection, but yes it's slow because all data is shuffled into your machine, which isn't how Spark should be used

Comment: thanks for your answer. I know "collect" and stuff like that should be avoided as much as possible, but I am afraid I need that one..

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
df.select("colName").dropDuplicates().rdd.map(row =>row(0)).collect.toList
```

Or you can try

```
df.select("colName").dropDuplicates().withColumn("colName", collect_list("colName")).rdd.map(row =>row(0)).collect
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, but it seems to take about the same time, unfortunately.. I have been able to bypass this problem (without the need to use the df) via importing the list of all possible cases directly and then filtering my table and checking if the df_after_filter.count() equals zero or not

Comment: yes the solution would take the same time ( more may be) I just wrote alternative ways of doing the logic. Collect is an expensive as it brings all the data into driver node. So until you use collect method, speed would not improve.